# undefined reference to `_gettimeofday' using vcpkg

Tags: c, vcpkg, mxchip

I am building in C with VS2022 this [mxchip A3166 firmware](https://github.com/azure-rtos/getting-started/tree/master/MXChip/AZ3166) and I installed vcpkg in my win11 system. I have been trying for hours to get a timestamp but I'm now settling for anything closer such as time difference but I can't get to run any time related library methods, I always get this error:

```
FAILED: app/mxchip_azure_iot.elf 
  cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\PROGRA~2\GNUARM~1\102021~1.10\bin\AR19DD~1.EXE -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -g3 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-builtin -fno-common -Wall -Wshadow -Wdouble-promotion -Werror -Wno-unused-parameter -O0 --specs=nano.specs -Wl,--gc-sections,-print-memory-usage    -TMXChip_AZ3166.ld -Wl,-Map=mxchip_azure_iot.map @CMakeFiles\mxchip_azure_iot.rsp -o app\mxchip_azure_iot.elf  && cd ."
  c:/progra~2/gnuarm~1/102021~1.10/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: c:/progra~2/gnuarm~1/102021~1.10/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libg_nano.a(lib_a-gettimeofdayr.o): in function `_gettimeofday_r':
  gettimeofdayr.c:(.text._gettimeofday_r+0xe): undefined reference to `_gettimeofday'
```

This is the code

```c
#include <time.h>
time_t prior_t;

static UINT append_device_timestamp(NX_AZURE_IOT_JSON_WRITER* json_writer)
{
    time_t curr_t;
    double diff_t;

    printf("Calc Diff...\n");
    time(&curr_t);

    if (!prior_t)
    {
        diff_t = difftime(curr_t, prior_t);
        printf("Diff = %f\n", diff_t);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("prior_t was NULL");
    }
    
    prior_t = curr_t;
}
```

I can see this time.h lib which I'm trying to use above in GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain\10 2021.10\arm-none-eabi\include

```c
/*
 * time.h
 * 
 * Struct and function declarations for dealing with time.
 */

#ifndef _TIME_H_
#define _TIME_H_

#include "_ansi.h"
#include <sys/cdefs.h>
#include <sys/reent.h>

#define __need_size_t
#define __need_NULL
#include <stddef.h>

/* Get _CLOCKS_PER_SEC_ */
#include <machine/time.h>

#ifndef _CLOCKS_PER_SEC_
#define _CLOCKS_PER_SEC_ 1000
#endif

#define CLOCKS_PER_SEC _CLOCKS_PER_SEC_
#define CLK_TCK CLOCKS_PER_SEC

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/timespec.h>

#if __POSIX_VISIBLE >= 200809
#include <sys/_locale.h>
#endif

_BEGIN_STD_C

struct tm
{
  int   tm_sec;
  int   tm_min;
  int   tm_hour;
  int   tm_mday;
  int   tm_mon;
  int   tm_year;
  int   tm_wday;
  int   tm_yday;
  int   tm_isdst;
#ifdef __TM_GMTOFF
  long  __TM_GMTOFF;
#endif
#ifdef __TM_ZONE
  const char *__TM_ZONE;
#endif
};

clock_t    clock (void);
double     difftime (time_t _time2, time_t _time1);
time_t     mktime (struct tm *_timeptr);
time_t     time (time_t *_timer);
#ifndef _REENT_ONLY
char      *asctime (const struct tm *_tblock);
char      *ctime (const time_t *_time);
struct tm *gmtime (const time_t *_timer);
struct tm *localtime (const time_t *_timer);
#endif
size_t     strftime (char *__restrict _s,
                 size_t _maxsize, const char *__restrict _fmt,
                 const struct tm *__restrict _t);

#if __POSIX_VISIBLE >= 200809
extern size_t strftime_l (char *__restrict _s, size_t _maxsize,
              const char *__restrict _fmt,
              const struct tm *__restrict _t, locale_t _l);
#endif

char      *asctime_r    (const struct tm *__restrict,
                 char *__restrict);
char      *ctime_r  (const time_t *, char *);
struct tm *gmtime_r     (const time_t *__restrict,
                 struct tm *__restrict);
struct tm *localtime_r  (const time_t *__restrict,
                 struct tm *__restrict);

_END_STD_C

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#if __XSI_VISIBLE
char      *strptime (const char *__restrict,
                 const char *__restrict,
                 struct tm *__restrict);
#endif
#if __GNU_VISIBLE
char *strptime_l (const char *__restrict, const char *__restrict,
          struct tm *__restrict, locale_t);
#endif

#if __POSIX_VISIBLE
void      tzset     (void);
#endif
void      _tzset_r  (struct _reent *);

/* getdate functions */

#ifdef HAVE_GETDATE
#if __XSI_VISIBLE >= 4
#ifndef _REENT_ONLY
#define getdate_err (*__getdate_err())
int *__getdate_err (void);

struct tm * getdate (const char *);
/* getdate_err is set to one of the following values to indicate the error.
     1  the DATEMSK environment variable is null or undefined,
     2  the template file cannot be opened for reading,
     3  failed to get file status information,
     4  the template file is not a regular file,
     5  an error is encountered while reading the template file,
     6  memory allication failed (not enough memory available),
     7  there is no line in the template that matches the input,
     8  invalid input specification  */
#endif /* !_REENT_ONLY */
#endif /* __XSI_VISIBLE >= 4 */

#if __GNU_VISIBLE
/* getdate_r returns the error code as above */
int     getdate_r (const char *, struct tm *);
#endif /* __GNU_VISIBLE */
#endif /* HAVE_GETDATE */

/* defines for the opengroup specifications Derived from Issue 1 of the SVID.  */
#if __SVID_VISIBLE || __XSI_VISIBLE
extern __IMPORT long _timezone;
extern __IMPORT int _daylight;
#endif
#if __POSIX_VISIBLE
extern __IMPORT char *_tzname[2];

/* POSIX defines the external tzname being defined in time.h */
#ifndef tzname
#define tzname _tzname
#endif
#endif /* __POSIX_VISIBLE */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#include <sys/features.h>

#ifdef __CYGWIN__
#include <cygwin/time.h>
#endif /*__CYGWIN__*/

#if defined(_POSIX_TIMERS)

#include <signal.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* Clocks, P1003.1b-1993, p. 263 */

int clock_settime (clockid_t clock_id, const struct timespec *tp);
int clock_gettime (clockid_t clock_id, struct timespec *tp);
int clock_getres (clockid_t clock_id, struct timespec *res);

/* Create a Per-Process Timer, P1003.1b-1993, p. 264 */

int timer_create (clockid_t clock_id,
    struct sigevent *__restrict evp,
    timer_t *__restrict timerid);

/* Delete a Per_process Timer, P1003.1b-1993, p. 266 */

int timer_delete (timer_t timerid);

/* Per-Process Timers, P1003.1b-1993, p. 267 */

int timer_settime (timer_t timerid, int flags,
    const struct itimerspec *__restrict value,
    struct itimerspec *__restrict ovalue);
int timer_gettime (timer_t timerid, struct itimerspec *value);
int timer_getoverrun (timer_t timerid);

/* High Resolution Sleep, P1003.1b-1993, p. 269 */

int nanosleep (const struct timespec  *rqtp, struct timespec *rmtp);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif /* _POSIX_TIMERS */

#if defined(_POSIX_CLOCK_SELECTION)

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int clock_nanosleep (clockid_t clock_id, int flags,
    const struct timespec *rqtp, struct timespec *rmtp);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* _POSIX_CLOCK_SELECTION */

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* CPU-time Clock Attributes, P1003.4b/D8, p. 54 */

/* values for the clock enable attribute */

#define CLOCK_ENABLED  1  /* clock is enabled, i.e. counting execution time */
#define CLOCK_DISABLED 0  /* clock is disabled */

/* values for the pthread cputime_clock_allowed attribute */

#define CLOCK_ALLOWED    1 /* If a thread is created with this value a */
                           /*   CPU-time clock attached to that thread */
                           /*   shall be accessible. */
#define CLOCK_DISALLOWED 0 /* If a thread is created with this value, the */
                           /*   thread shall not have a CPU-time clock */
                           /*   accessible. */

/* Flag indicating time is "absolute" with respect to the clock
   associated with a time.  Value 4 is historic. */

#define TIMER_ABSTIME   4

/* Manifest Constants, P1003.1b-1993, p. 262 */

#if __GNU_VISIBLE
#define CLOCK_REALTIME_COARSE   ((clockid_t) 0)
#endif

#define CLOCK_REALTIME      ((clockid_t) 1)

/* Manifest Constants, P1003.4b/D8, p. 55 */

#if defined(_POSIX_CPUTIME)

/* When used in a clock or timer function call, this is interpreted as
   the identifier of the CPU_time clock associated with the PROCESS
   making the function call.  */

#define CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID ((clockid_t) 2)

#endif

#if defined(_POSIX_THREAD_CPUTIME)

/*  When used in a clock or timer function call, this is interpreted as
    the identifier of the CPU_time clock associated with the THREAD
    making the function call.  */

#define CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID ((clockid_t) 3)

#endif

#if defined(_POSIX_MONOTONIC_CLOCK)

/*  The identifier for the system-wide monotonic clock, which is defined
 *  as a clock whose value cannot be set via clock_settime() and which
 *  cannot have backward clock jumps. */

#define CLOCK_MONOTONIC     ((clockid_t) 4)

#endif

#if __GNU_VISIBLE

#define CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW ((clockid_t) 5)

#define CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE  ((clockid_t) 6)

#define CLOCK_BOOTTIME      ((clockid_t) 7)

#define CLOCK_REALTIME_ALARM    ((clockid_t) 8)

#define CLOCK_BOOTTIME_ALARM    ((clockid_t) 9)

#endif

#if defined(_POSIX_CPUTIME)

/* Accessing a Process CPU-time CLock, P1003.4b/D8, p. 55 */

int clock_getcpuclockid (pid_t pid, clockid_t *clock_id);

#endif /* _POSIX_CPUTIME */

#if defined(_POSIX_CPUTIME) || defined(_POSIX_THREAD_CPUTIME)

/* CPU-time Clock Attribute Access, P1003.4b/D8, p. 56 */

int clock_setenable_attr (clockid_t clock_id, int attr);
int clock_getenable_attr (clockid_t clock_id, int *attr);

#endif /* _POSIX_CPUTIME or _POSIX_THREAD_CPUTIME */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* _TIME_H_ */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.h` file is not the library. It contains only information about function names and, return types and parameters taken. The actual function call has to be in `.c` source files, objects files or library files.

The linker error shows that you do not have the function "body" in those files. It is probably not implemented for your target (quite common in the embedded world)

Comment: is the general solution to copy paste time.c from c library, save the file in the same directory where the .h file sits, would generally the linker pick the c file with this approach?

Comment: @SergioSolorzano no it is not, especially for uCs

Comment: if I don't add the body file can you please guide me what to do next so I can google from there?

Comment: @SergioSolorzano no easy solution, ask MCP\

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll look around. By way of constructive feedback, acronyms to answer can be a bit confusing for a newbie like me, don't know what uCs and MCP are :)

Comment: In case it helps anyone, with the above firmware I used HAL_GetTick() in stm32 anytime to get ms from boot